# Backup options or snapshots of Google Cloud Storage data?

Tags: backup, google-cloud-storage

I pulled data into Google BigQuery tables and also generate some new datasets based on these data daily.

These original data and generated datesets, I would save in Google Cloud Storage for two purposes,

1. These are the backup copy of my Google BigQuery data.
2. Also some of these datasets saved in Google Cloud Storage would be dump loaded to AWS elasticsearch (so they are also the backup copy data for AWS Elasticsearch)
3. BigQuery or AWS Elasticsearch may only keep 2 months to 1 year data. So the data older than that, I only have one copy on Google Cloud Storage. (I need to have some backup options, such as 1 months snapshots for Google Cloud Storage which I can go back to if needed.)

**My questions are**

How could I keep a backup or snapshot of Google Cloud Storage data to prevent the data loss in Google Cloud Storage. Such as let me at least trace back 7 days or 1 months of the data in Google Cloud Storage?

So in the case of data lost, (accidentally delete data etc), I can go back a few days to get the data back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can backup your cloud data to some local storage, CloudBerry has option "Cloud to Local".

Comment: There is also an ability to make Cloud to Cloud migration

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the software I am using myself- Cloudberry backup that can backup cloud storage to local storage or to other cloud storage.The toolsupports various cloud storages i.e.Amazon, Google, Azure etc. You can also download and upload data with the help of the tool, thus it's better to install it on Google VM.